# SQL When user select a data the other data will also be selected

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to do is when user select an item from the database the beginv will also be selected.

```php
    <?php
    $ret=mysqli_query($con,"select ItemName, beginv from tblitem");
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($ret))
    {?>

    <option value="<?php echo $row['ItemName'];?>"><?php echo $row['ItemName'];]?></option>
    <?php } ?>
```

I want that when user select the Item the Item beginv will also be selected

Comment: what you want to do here is not clear

Answer (score 1):

when performing loop and arrived the "beginv" then the option will be selected following this code

```
  <option value="<?php echo $row['ItemName'];?>" <?php if($row['ItemName']=='beginv'){echo "selected";} ?> ><?php echo $row['ItemName'];]?></option>
```

Comment: so if I will get the beginv post value .. $row['beginv']?